# Simple questiong regarding styling of <hr/> tag

Tags: html, css

I am using a hr tag on our page but it looks weird in

[IE9 http://img580.imageshack.us/img580/1295/unleddlz.png](http://img580.imageshack.us/img580/1295/unleddlz.png)

Notice the left-hand-side

CSS is

```
.greyLine {color: rgb(252,252,252); height: 1px; background-color: rgb(252,252,252);}
```

What's wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try changing the `border` property, likely the `border-style` property, in particular.

Comment: Sathya why did you remove the picture?

Comment: He didn't, he linked it to the text, but not very thoroughly.

Answer (score 1):

```
.greyLine
{
   border: none;
   border-top: 1px solid rgb(252,252,253);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.greyLine {
height: 1px;
color: rgb(252,252,252);
background-color: rgb(252,252,252);
border: none;
}
```

You had it right, just needed to remove the border. Doing it your way plus border:none allows you to change the height if needed. Good luck. Source: [How To Style HR with CSS](http://www.syntaxxx.com/how-to-style-hr-with-css/)